# Python dataframe HTML display outside jupyter

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table, display

I would like to create a HTML file (say 'my_file.html') containing a dataframe and I would like to have a rending similar to Jupyter's dataFrame, ie

```
from IPython.display import display
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'new': {Timestamp('2008-09-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
                           Timestamp('2008-09-02 00:00:00'): -0.0},
                   'old': {Timestamp('2008-09-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
                           Timestamp('2008-09-02 00:00:00'): -0.0},
                   'diff':{Timestamp('2008-09-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
                           Timestamp('2008-09-02 00:00:00'): 0.0}})
display(df)
```

But when I do

```
df.to_html('my_file.html')
```

The rending is a simple table without Jupyter formatting

```html
<div>
<style scoped>
    .dataframe tbody tr th:only-of-type {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .dataframe tbody tr th {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .dataframe thead th {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>new</th>
      <th>old</th>
      <th>diff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>2008-09-01</th>
      <td>0.0000</td>
      <td>0.0000</td>
      <td>0.0000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2008-09-02</th>
      <td>-0.0000</td>
      <td>-0.0000</td>
      <td>0.0000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Any idea how to amend the code to make the display similar to Jupyter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jupyter CSS style sheet is the reason for the beautiful table. 
You can copy the relevant `css` rules from the [`index.css`](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/3d07723da5543c8bfb4f509f00b95f75789d38c7/packages/rendermime/style/index.css#L341) file of Jupyter.
After crafting the style sheet, wrap the output of `df.to_html()` inside a `<div>`.

```html
<div class="p-Widget jp-RenderedHTMLCommon jp-RenderedHTML jp-mod-trusted jp-OutputArea-output" data-mime-type="text/html">
<!-- Output of df.to_html() -->
</div>
```

Here are the crafted style sheet with your example output:

```css
/* jupyterlab/packages/theme-light-extension/style/variables.css */
:root {
  --jp-ui-font-color0: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  --jp-ui-font-color1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  --jp-layout-color0: white;
  --jp-rendermime-error-background: #fdd;
  --jp-rendermime-table-row-background: #ddd;
  --jp-rendermime-table-row-hover-background: #aaa;
}

/* Tables */
.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: none;
  color: var(--jp-ui-font-color1);
  font-size: 12px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon thead {
  border-bottom: var(--jp-border-width) solid var(--jp-border-color1);
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon td,
.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon th,
.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon tr {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  max-width: none;
  border: none;
}

.jp-RenderedMarkdown.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon td,
.jp-RenderedMarkdown.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon th {
  max-width: none;
}

:not(.jp-RenderedMarkdown).jp-RenderedHTMLCommon td,
:not(.jp-RenderedMarkdown).jp-RenderedHTMLCommon th,
:not(.jp-RenderedMarkdown).jp-RenderedHTMLCommon tr {
  text-align: right;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: var(--jp-layout-color0);
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: var(--jp-rendermime-table-row-background);
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon tbody tr:hover {
  background: var(--jp-rendermime-table-row-hover-background);
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
}

.jp-RenderedHTMLCommon p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-Widget jp-RenderedHTMLCommon jp-RenderedHTML jp-mod-trusted jp-OutputArea-output" data-mime-type="text/html">
<style scoped="">
    .dataframe tbody tr th:only-of-type {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .dataframe tbody tr th {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .dataframe thead th {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
<table class="dataframe" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>new</th>
      <th>old</th>
      <th>diff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>2008-09-01</th>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2008-09-02</th>
      <td>-0.0</td>
      <td>-0.0</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am missing something. I have copied the second code snippet into an html file, but the display is still the same as before when I open that file (by double clicking on it). Any idea what am I doing wrong? (spoiler alert, I am a complete newbie in html :))

Comment: You have to copy the first part (the style sheet or css) into a `<style></style>` element in the html head.

Comment: @cpeusteuche There are actually many ways to include CSS code into a HTML file. Please refer to [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp).